# Restart tor browser after 30 seconds

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I want to know how to restart tor browser automatically after 30 seconds or a way to automatically apply the new identity shortcut after 30 seconds

Comment: What do you imagine this would achieve?

Comment: just want to open a particular link in multiple places